# CUDA on OSX - NVCC can't find STL array header

Tags: cuda, osx-mavericks, nvcc

I'm in the process of porting a CUDA app from Windows to OSX, and am unable to get anything to compile. (Ultimately I'm trying to get Xcode to build my `.cu` source with a custom build rule, but that's another story [unless someone has an updated CUDA plugin that works with Xcode 5].)

Here's what happens in Terminal:

```
$ nvcc -ccbin /usr/bin/clang -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --compile -cudart static -o Visualizer.cu.obj Visualizer.cu
Visualizer.cu:4:10: fatal error: 'array' file not found
#include <array>
         ^
1 error generated.
$
```

Here's the top of the source file in question:

```
#include "Visualizer.cuh"

#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

#include "CudaHelpers.h"
#include "OpenGLHelpers.h"
#include "GLError.h"
#include "Files.h"


Visualizer::Visualizer(void)
{
    /// constructor code removed for brevity
}


Visualizer::~Visualizer(void)
{
}

/// snip
```

It appears that `nvcc` isn't able to locate the STL `array` header. (It's worth noting that `array` appears to be a C++11 header, though I'm not sure if that's relevant.)

I find it strange that it can't find `array`, but `iostream` isn't a problem.

Any suggestions? The same source file builds under Win7 x64 using the same CUDA SDK version (5.5).

On the off chance that it's helpful, here's the output of `env` in the same terminal session I'm using to launch `nvcc`:

```
$ env
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/sw/7xhtxxnd39x8r5zy9tkq94780000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-JgrEAi/Render
USER=dlively
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-HkiDEO/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
__CHECKFIX1436934=1
PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
PWD=/Users/dlively/projects/thesis/GoLightly/GoLightly
DBUS_LAUNCHD_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET=/tmp/launch-335uC6/unix_domain_listener
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
SHLVL=1
COLORFGBG=7;0
HOME=/Users/dlively
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0
LOGNAME=my_user_name
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/Users/dlively/projects/thesis/GoLightly
$
```

It occurred to me that the STL headers/libs simply aren't referenced by any environment variable, but I'm not sure where, exactly, those are located, or the best way (environment variable? `nvcc.profile`? `-I...` command line option?) to supply that information.

Help!

**Update**

All of the CUDA samples build correctly (via `make`). However, if I add a line

```
#include <array>
```

to any source file (even in the samples), it fails.

**Update 2**

Output of `nvcc --verbose`:

```
#$ _SPACE_=
#$ _CUDART_=cudart
#$ _HERE_=/usr/local/cuda/bin
#$ _THERE_=/usr/local/cuda/bin
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=
#$ _TARGET_DIR_=
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=64
#$ TOP=/usr/local/cuda/bin/..
#$ NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/bin/../nvvm/libdevice
#$ PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin/../open64/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin/../nvvm/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
#$ INCLUDES="-I/usr/local/cuda/bin/../include" "-I/usr/local/include/" "-I/usr/local/include/**"
#$ LIBRARIES=  "-L/usr/local/cuda/bin/../lib"
#$ CUDAFE_FLAGS=
#$ OPENCC_FLAGS=
#$ PTXAS_FLAGS=
#$ "/usr/bin"/clang -stdlib=libstdc++ -D__CUDA_ARCH__=300 -E -x c++    -DCUDA_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS  -D__CUDACC__ -D__NVCC__  -std=c++11 "-I/usr/local/cuda/bin/../include" "-I/usr/local/include/" "-I/usr/local/include/**"    -D"_MBCS" -include "cuda_runtime.h" -m64 -o "/var/folders/sw/7xhtxxnd39x8r5zy9tkq94780000gn/T//tmpxft_00001010_00000000-6_Visualizer.cpp1.ii" "Visualizer.cu"
Visualizer.cu:4:10: fatal error: 'array' file not found
#include <array>
         ^
1 error generated.
# --error 0x1 --
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Can you compile an ordinary clang/xcode project with array? Even if you solve the locating problem, its possible that nvcc may not be happy with array. One typical suggestion is to separate your c++11 code and cuda code into separate modules and compile the non-cuda modules with the standard clang toolchain.

Comment: This isn't an nvcc problem, it is a clang problem. Try adding `-Xcompiler="--std=c++11"` to the compile statement

Comment: @talonmies proper flag would be --stdlib=libc++ - but I'm not sure if it would work with NVCC and I know it was definitely not recommended as of CUDA toolkit 5.5 and probably 6.0.

Comment: @Eugene: according to  [this](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) the `--std` option is required to activiate C++11 language features in clang.

Comment: @RobertCrovella actually, I can't compile anything with clang that includes `<array>`. Hmmm. I'm including the `--std=c++11` parameter which seems to have no effect. I'll update my question with more info.

Comment: @talonmies --std=c++11 is for language features. It may be required to compile source file with the header, but to actually add the <array> to include path you need to specify the --stdlib flag. On XCode5 beta I used to specify both to play with C++11.

Answer (score 2):

This is C++11 header that is not available in the libstdc++ version that is available on Mac. Note that   it is not advisable to link CUDA runtime library with libc++ so you should avoid these features in CUDA code.

A bit of details on confusing terms:

- libstdc++ - GNU C++ standard library. Apple ships fairly old version for compatibility purposes.
- libc++ - it's C++ standard library developed under LLVM umbrella. Apple actively participates in its development and links with it by default since, AFAIK, 10.9 and XCode 5.

**Update**

Note in your output flag "-stdlib=libstdc++" passed to clang. That's what selects the standard library.

Answer (score -2):

```
-Xcompiler="--stdlib=libstdc++"
```